# R - Using GoogleSignIn and ObserveEvent

Tags: r, shiny, google-authentication

I'm trying to add Google Sign in to a Shiny App. I'm using the googleAuthR package for the sign and I want to trigger some events when the user clicks "Sign in". However, I'm not getting the ObserveEvent to trigger when I click the "Sign in" button.

Below is a code example. I'm looking to have "This works" printed out when I click "Sign in".

```
library(shiny)
library(googleAuthR)

options(shiny.port=3694)
options(googleAuthR.webapp.client_id = "...")

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Sample Google Sign-In"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      googleSignInUI("demo")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      with(tags, dl(dt("Name"), dd(textOutput("g_name")),
                    dt("Email"), dd(textOutput("g_email")),
                    dt("Image"), dd(uiOutput("g_image")) ))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  sign_ins <- shiny::callModule(googleSignIn, "demo")

  output$g_name = renderText({ sign_ins()$name })
  output$g_email = renderText({ sign_ins()$email })
  output$g_image = renderUI({ img(src=sign_ins()$image) })

  observeEvent(input$demo, {
    print(paste("This works!"))
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `observeEvent` to somehow be dependent on the `sign_ins()`reactive, so an `observe()`with a `req()` would achieve what you are asking.  The `input$demo` is the module name, not the input within the module so wouldn't give you a signal to work from.  The below works:

```
library(shiny)
library(googleAuthR)

options(googleAuthR.webapp.client_id = "xxx")

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Sample Google Sign-In"),

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        googleSignInUI("demo")
      ),

      mainPanel(
        with(tags, dl(dt("Name"), dd(textOutput("g_name")),
                      dt("Email"), dd(textOutput("g_email")),
                      dt("Image"), dd(uiOutput("g_image")) ))
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  sign_ins <- shiny::callModule(googleSignIn, "demo")

  output$g_name = renderText({ sign_ins()$name })
  output$g_email = renderText({ sign_ins()$email })
  output$g_image = renderUI({ img(src=sign_ins()$image) })

  observe({
    req(sign_ins()$name)

    print("This works")

  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Great, do make it as an answer then so others can benefit and I get my rep points :)

Comment: Ahh, definitely - didn't know that was a feature. Thanks again and thanks for a great R package! :)